# How can I build a custom seeking bar for react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am trying to build a custom seeking Bar for a video Playing in react-native-video, which Library do you recommend I use ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you try building your own, as you have the event onSeek to listen to and the method seek change position.
If you are asking for suggestions regarding UI, I would suggest you look in to React Native Elements. You can use their slider (https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/slider) and do something like:

```
import { Slider } from 'react-native-elements';

<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Slider
    value={this.state.progress} // Which is updated by videoRef.onProgress listener
    onValueChange={value => videoRef.seek(value)} 
  />
  <Text>Value: {this.state.value}</Text>
</View>;
```

Comment: can you give a more clear or working example of what you referring to please!

Comment: Maybe an easier way to go at it would be https://github.com/itsnubix/react-native-video-controls.

Comment: It worked for me. I used this approach. But I was getting error due the fact that slider was returning decimal value. I used `Math.floor(value)` to convert into integer which fix the problem.